# Augmenting vue.js in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to augment vue js with additional mapping. I'm following this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins

I have created a file `vue.d.ts` under `./Definitions` (relative to my `main.ts`)
I have referenced it in my `main.ts`:

```
require("./Definitions/vue.d.ts");
```

In `vue.d.ts` I've put:

```
 // 1. Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types
import Vue from 'vue'

// 2. Specify a file with the types you want to augment
//    Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
    interface Vue {
        $myProperty: string
    }
}
```

But this:

```
var vm = new Vue()
console.log(vm.$myProperty);
```

Doesn't resolve.

I've tried changing `declare module 'vue/types/vue'` to just `declare module 'vue'`. This gives me an error: `"Cannot augument module 'vue' because it resolves to a non-module entity"`

The original vue typings are located under `{projectDir}\node_modules\@types\vue\index.d.ts`. I'm using webpack.

How do I do it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your project has `tsconfig.json`, you should set following `compilerOptions`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

        "baseUrl": ".",

        // other options go here

        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./typings"
        ]
    }
}
```

Once you do that, create `typings/vue` folder relative to `tsconfig.json` and the path you mentioned. Inside `typings/vue` folder, create `index.d.ts` file. Typically, your declaration file would look like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { AppStore } from '../../src/store/store';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    // Global properties can be declared
    // on the `VueConstructor` interface
    interface VueConstructor {
        // some more augmentation
    }

    // Properties added to Vue interface are added to Vue instance
    interface Vue {
        store$: AppStore;
    }
}
```

Prefer this approach over the one that you are trying to do as importing type files doesn't scale really well.

Also, with latest Vue.js, you don't need `node_modules/@types/vue` declarations. They are shipped as part of official `node_modules/vue` package. If you are doing that then you should delete those.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. But I think I have some setup problems - you are right, the bindings are supplied in `node_modules/vue`, but if I remove `node_modules/@types/vue`, my build process stops from working. I'll try to look at it more tomorrow

Comment: This is for sure the correct answer. I have cleaned everything and did it again. Then I added `vue-resource` to my `index.d.ts` augmentation and everything started to work. Not sure why it didn't at start. My VS still does not see the bindings, but I think I'll find a way to fix this. Thanks