# Make vue-resource work with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I seem to have an issue with typescript set up, as it does not see the typings provided by `vue-resource`. I think I managed to create a small example of the issue, unfortunately I do not know what to do next.

I have:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./built/",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": [ "es2017", "dom" ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./ViewModels/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ] 
}
```

`./ViewModels/vue-shims.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue;
}
```

`./ViewModels/Home/main.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
//const Vue = require('vue');

import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(<any>VueResource);

const v = new Vue(<any>{
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    },
    components: {
    }
});

//var vm = new Vue();
//console.log(vm.$http);
```

`./ViewModels/Home/Components/ProjectSelection/projectSelectionScripts.ts`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from 'vue-class-component';


const NewGroupItemName = "Create new group (drag project here)";


@Component({})
class ProjectSelectionComponent extends Vue {      
    created() {
        this.$http.get("url").then(response => {} => {

            });

    }
}

export default ProjectSelectionComponent
```

This is a cut from a huge project that I'm trying to fix. It maybe should not work, but it should compile. It doesn't though:

```
ViewModels/Home/Components/ProjectSelection/projectSelectionScripts.ts:15:14 - error TS2339: Property '$http' does not exist on type 'ProjectSelectionComponent'.

15         this.$http.get("url").then(response => {
                ~~~~~
```

My `.\node_modules` has:
`@types\node`, `@types\vue-resource` and a lot of other stuff.

`package.json` of the original big project:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "BigProject",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vue-resource": "^0.9.34",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bosket/core": "^0.4.2",
    "@bosket/tools": "^0.4.2",
    "@bosket/vue": "^0.4.2",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^1.35.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.36.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.2.0",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-cookie-law": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.3",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Any tips on what can be wrong here?

Comment: I'm unsure if this will solve the problem but you might need to augment that type so that the typescript compiler understands there's a $http property. I'm referring to: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann OMG, you are right. I've done this and it started to work. This is very weird because I actually stumbled on this problem during investigating on how to do augmentation in the first place. Now I need to figure out on how to move this to an original project. But this seems to be the answer and if you post it as one, I'll mark it

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann Also for both reference and if you have some ideas or solutions - my original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909703/augmenting-vue-js-in-typescript/50910863#50910863

Comment: it's actually been your original question that made me consider that augmenting might be necessary here. I've never actually used it myself in a project so I'm afraid I can't help you with this one, sorry. By looking at your original code it looks pretty much exactly what is provided in the documentation, so I'm confused myself.